# How to add generated attachment public link to "Public link Sharing" modal in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning, attachment, public-link-sharing

I have a Custom Object with Attachments enabled. When a user uploads a file I'd like to automatically create the Public Link for the attachment. To generate public link I use the code below.

```
ContentDocumentLink cdl = [SELECT id, contentDocument.id
                           FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                           WHERE linkedentityId = <customObject.id>];

ContentVersion cv = [SELECT id 
                     FROM ContentVersion 
                     WHERE contentdocumentid = :cdl.contentDocument.id];

ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.Name = cdl.contentDocument.title;
cd.ContentVersionId = cv.id;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser= true;
cd.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion=true;
cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit=false;
cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired=false;
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload= true;
CD.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = false;
insert cd;

cd = [SELECT id, DistributionPublicUrl
      FROM ContentDistribution 
      WHERE id = cd.id];
```

After generating a public link for attachment, it doesn't appear in "Public Link Sharing" modal, the screen below.
[image]

One of the solutions is to create a custom field(text area) on this custom object and put the link to it, but when the user opens the "Public Link Sharing" and click "Create Link" it will create a second public link for the attachment which I want to avoid. Is there any way to put this public link which was generated from apex code to this "Public link Sharing" modal?